# GetFileInfo() and LastWriteTime() is giving an error : Index was outside the bounds of the array

Tags: vb.net, pdf, indexoutofboundsexception, last-modified

I have following code spinet:

**UPDATE**

```
(code above this code is creation of pdf file)
Dim PdfFileInfo As FileInfo
Dim PdfModificationTime As Date
If (FileIO.FileSystem.FileExists(strPdfFileName)) Then
   PdfFileInfo = FileIO.FileSystem.GetFileInfo(strPdfFileName)
   PdfModificationTime = PdfFileInfo.LastWriteTime()
End If
```

File is exist, but when I use `GetFileInfo()` and `LastWriteTime()` it gives an **error : "Index was outside the bounds of the array"**

I tried lot of things, but no luck... :(

> **SOLVED**

Issue has been solved, answered separately !

Comment: I assume that you dont get the exception at both lines, so where exactly is it raised? Post the stacktrace.

Comment: When I add those two lines, PdfFileInfo = FileIO.FileSystem.GetFileInfo(strPdfFileName)
   PdfModificationTime = PdfFileInfo.LastWriteTime() it gives me an exception

Comment: I can not get stacktrace because of some reasons(so I am stuck actually, I know this is runtime error), could GetFileInfo() return null even if file exists?

Comment: I create pdf file and then immediately executes above code...

Comment: You don't get an `IndexOutOfRangeException` when an object is `null`, that's a `NullReferenceException`. You get the exception if you try to access an item of a list or array at an index which doesn't exist. So like here: `int[] ints={1};int second=ints[1];`

Comment: I know about out of index exception scenario, So I am confused here because Ideally I am not really using any array or index related code. But as per GetFileInfo() doc , it says , An exception is not thrown if the file does not exist; rather, it will be thrown the first time the object's properties are accessed.

Comment: That exception cannot be thrown by that code you posted. Something smells fishy here. Why can't you post the stack trace? If you do that you will have the answer in five minutes

Comment: Because I have only logs :(. And according to logs, code executes correctly till these lines and doesn't go beyond these two lines.

Comment: Please take a look here [mcve].  We can't possible hope to duplicate your problem with the code you have supplied. Include the necessary code including declarations of the variables mentioned and  we might be able to figure out what's wrong.

Comment: code updated with variable declarations.

Comment: If you only have a log of what went wrong, does that mean that a customer is getting the error and you can't reproduce it? Could it be that the log is not saying what you intend it to say? What happens if you use System.IO.FileInfo instead of the My.Computer methods?

Comment: What about the declaration of strPdfFileName? Is that definitely a string? If so then as @TimSchmelter says, you cant possibly get an IndexOutOfRangeException in this code. Hover your mouse over the variables and check the values.

Comment: You could have the IndexOutOfRangeException happening in your logging code and the logging code is somehow managing to log it's own error.

Comment: So what is in the log exactly? You should be writing to stacktrace there when an exception is thrown

Comment: @JyotheWhiff Are you using [Option Strict On](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs.aspx) to ensure that all data types are correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two important points are Here..

1. possibility of error at those lines which I have mentioned in the question
2. error : Index was outside the bounds of the array

**Lets talk about 1st:**

---

Many told that error at those lines could not be possible, I thought that too while writing a code at first, but got an error which was showing in logs.

Then I have read documentation about **system function** `GetFileInfo()`.

What they say, this function gives information about file which system has **"cashed"** in its memory, `system does this cashing periodically`.

Now just think, system just cashed the file system information in its memory, now you have created a file and written something in a file and called the function `GetFileInfo()`.

Saw the problem? See when you called a function `GetFileInfo()`, system doesn't have even a file object cashed in the memory. So we get `fileinfo object null` here and when you try to get `LastWriteTime()` of null object,here system throws an exception.

**Solution :** I have put null check using while loop on fileInfo object that is `PdfFileInfo` in code (and yes this problem is been tested and solved .... :) )

---

**Now talk about 2nd:**

The code referred in a question was not in a try block so any exception thrown by this function block got received in calling function. Here calling function resolved this exception in its own way and thrown an exception "Index was outside the bounds of the array" which was relevant for calling function but not reflected actual exception thrown by `GetFileInfo()`.

**Solution :** put this code block in try-catch block

Thanks for all comments and discussions... :) !